# ColdFusion 2018 - prevent Tomcat error pages

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion

I have received a vulnerability for our IIS 10, ColdFusion 2018 server as follows:

> Vulnerability Description:
> Server Exposed technology version in 404 server response.

If you try to access a non-existent page, the server responds with normal
404 page. But if you send an invalid path (which in theory responds with a 400 - a bad response) the server responds the same version 404 page but with
Tomcat ISAPI redirector version.

> This server - 
> Don't show version in server banner
> Don't show version in 404 response 
> Don't have a BigIP load balancer in response header

Updated:
I have some further information.  The URL is in the format of:  https://xxx.xxxx.com/..;/

This seems to bypass the IIS 404 and instead serves up the Tomcat 404 from Coldfusion.

My question is, how do I change the Tomcat error page within the ColdFusion 2018 Tomcat?  Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

IIS should have put a config file in the root of your site: `web.config`. I always make sure this is checked into source control. Add a `<httpErrors>` node and enter the path to a `404.cfm` file. This one is at the root of the site (you can name it whatever you like).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" path="/404.cfm" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks.  In "Error Pages" on the website for "404" in the IIS administrator it's set to "Insert content from the static file into the error response" pointing to the default page.  When I go to a random URL that does not exist on the website, I get the default IIS 404 error page, but for some reason on some kind of scan they are seeing the tomcat error page from coldfusion.  I have no idea where this is coming from so I thought I might need to tackle this at the tomcat side.

Comment: They don't have an exact set of steps to recreate? I've dealt with dozens of these security scans from 3rd party testers and they usually have a comprehensive break down of how they got to the error. Now, WHY the error appears is usually a unique hell of its own.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  All we got was a description of the error.  I have requested more detail, but so far, no luck.

Comment: See above.  I added the URL format to recreate.